# Recommendation Engines for Java applications

Tags: java, recommendation-engine, mahout

I was wondering if there is any open source recommendation engine available? It should suggest something like Amazon and Netflix. I have heard of a framework called [Apache Mahout - Taste](http://mahout.apache.org/). I am trying it next week. It would be great if you can share your valuable thoughts.

Answer (score 16):

I'm the developer of [Mahout](http://mahout.apache.org/) / [Taste](http://people.apache.org/~isabel/site/taste.html), and hope it will do what you need, but in the interest of balanced coverage, let me also point you at:

- [Duine](http://duineframework.org/)
- [CoFE](http://eecs.oregonstate.edu/iis/CoFE/)
- [Cofi](http://www.nongnu.org/cofi/)

Comment: is Apache Mahout still being used for 2013?

Comment: Yes. I don't contribute to it at this point and am generally focused on 'next-gen' projects, at http://myrrix.com and now at Cloudera.

Comment: I've noticed that Apache Mahout on Apache is not that updated where is the updated version located?

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

Apache Mahout is the only one I have found for this area (I have been looking recently too).

Though [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) may also be an option.

Answer (score 2):

I had to work with open source recommendation systems and these are the ones that I found:

Duine, Apache Mahout, OpenSlopeOne, Cofi, SUGGEST and Vogoo.

More details:

Apache Mahout constitutes a Java framework in the data mining area. It has incorporated the Taste Recommender System, a collaborative engine for personalized recommendations.

Vogoo is a PHP framework that implements an collaborative filtering recommender system. It also presents a Slope-One code.

A Java version of the Collaborative Filtering method is implemented in the Cofi library. It was developed by Daniel Lemire, the creator of the Slope-One algorithms. There is also an PHP version available in Lemire's webpage.

OpenSlopeOne offers an Slope One implementation on PHP that cares about performance.

SUGGEST is a recommendation library made by George Karkys and distributed in a binary format.

I described everything I found out here on my blog:
http://girlincomputerscience.blogspot.com.br/2012/11/open-source-recommendation-systems.html

hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

I just started using [easyrec](http://easyrec.org/).  The forums are not very active, though I did get my questions answered.  Plus they have a demo server so you can test drive the recommendation tools without installing anything.  I liked their [javascript API](http://easyrec.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php?title=JavaScript_API_v0.97) and way to track recommendations of different types of items.  Currently, they only support the [slope one](http://easyrec.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php?title=Tuning_Guide) recommender--if you are looking for flexibility in this regard, mahout [wins hands down](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAHOUT/Recommender+Documentation) (though you can [write your own plugins](http://easyrec.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php?title=Plugin_Guide) for easyrec).

Answer (score 2):

[lenskit](http://lenskit.org/) seems another good recommendation engine in Java, provided by the grouplens team.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking more for the raw engine, rather than something specifically configured for amazon or netflix, then [Minion](https://minion.dev.java.net/) provides 'document similarity measures'.